# Почему передается не та функция?

Tags: javascript, ооп, this

Имеется такой кусок самописного плагина для валидации форм:

```js
;(() => {
    class Validation {

      constructor(options) {
        this.fields = options.fields;
        this.formElement = document.querySelector(options.formSelector);

      }

      init() {

        //Инициализация событий проверки полей
        if (Object.prototype.toString.call(this.fields) === '[object Array]') {

          this.fields.map((item) => {

            fieldElement = document.querySelector(item.fieldSelector);

            this._connectEventListeners(fieldElement, 'blur change ready', (e) => {
              //target - DOM элемент, поле
              //item.text - Условие, по которому нужно проверять строку или регулярное выражение
              //item.required - Обязательное ли поле

              const target = event.target;

              if (this.fieldTest(target, item.test, item.required) === false) {
                let failCallback = item.onFail ? item.onFail(target, item.test) : this.onFailField(item, target);
              } else {
                let succesCallback = item.onSuccess ? item.onSuccess(target, item.test) : this.onSuccessField(item, target);
              }

            })

          })


        }

      }


      _connectEventListeners(target, events, callback) {
        eventsList = events.split(' ');
        console.log(target)
        console.log(callback)


        for (let i = 0; i < eventsList.length; i++) {
          target.addEventListener(target, callback);
        }
      }

    })();
```

Проблема состоит в следующем:
В данную функцию `this._connectEventListeners` передается три аргумента:

1. первый - DOM элемент к которому привязывается событие(target)
2. второй - список событий(events)
3. третий - функция, которая будет вызываться при срабатывании обработчика события (callback)

Третьим аргументом я передаю функцию, но передается не та, что нужна:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чем проблема?

Answer (score 2):

В callback вы передаёте функцию, которая принимает аргумент "e", но ниже, в теле этой функции, используется имя "event". Попробуйте или использовать "e" или переименовать аргумент на event.

В данный момент ниже по коду у вас target === undefined

Comment: Вообще это тоже ошибка, но оно все равно правильно работало, уже поправил.

Проблема не ушла, передается функция init по какой-то причине